# C how to add value to char and limit it so its will give only small letter ('z' + 2 = 'b')

Tags: c

I need to decode a string in c.
each char in the string I add him the value: 2^pos and then get the wanted letter.
but if I do 'z' + 2 its not going to give me a small letter. ( i will get a special char "|")

i thought about doing something like that:

(
value = 2^pos)

```
if (*(arr + k) >= 'a' && *(arr + k) <= 'z')
    {
        if (pos == 0)
        {
            value = 1;
        }
        if ('z' - (*(arr + k)) <= value)
        {
            *(arr + k) = 'a' + (value - ('z' - *(arr + k)));
        }
        else
        { 
            *(arr + k) += value;
        }
        pos++;
    }
```

I also understand that there is a trick with %26 but i cant find the logic of it before doing it.

Comment: Three things: 1) For any pointer or array `a` and index `k`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. The latter is usually easier to read and understand (and write); 2) To check if a character is a lower-case letter use [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower); 3) Any arithmetic on characters will be *very* dependent on encoding. Your calculations depend on the ASCII encoding, which isn't mandated by the C specification.

Comment: @EraoS  I do not see where there is calculated the expression value: 2^pos.

Comment: As for your problem (and very ASCII dependent as well), consider the letter `'a'` to be equivalent to `0` and `'z'` equivalent to `25`. The realize that you can simply use addition and **modulo** operators to keep your values in the range of `0` to `25`. Then use the equivalence to turn the value back into a character.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow its in the general while loop i just showed you the if statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i thought c is woking good with ASCII values. mybad than

Comment: @SomeprogrammerDude this point i actually understand because there is a total of 26letter there but when i think in mathematic way i can't come up with a formula for it

Comment: `(value + addition) % range` will create a value between `0` and `range - 1`.

Comment: Regarding character encoding, C itself is agnostic to any specific character encoding. ASCII is "working good", but only on systems which is using ASCII encoding (which admittedly is almost all systems these days).

Answer (score 1):

a..=z is 26 characters, so you can get the character and subtract it by 'a' or 'A' or whatever. You can use that value to find modulo 26 and upon adding that remainder to 'a' or 'A' will follow the cycle. Here's sample code:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 26+10; ++j) {
        printf("%c ", (j%26) + 'a');
}
```

or

```
for (int j = 'a'; j <= 'z'+10; ++j) {
        printf("%c ", ((j-'a')%26) + 'a');
}
```